# II7 statistics tracking

Tags: iis-7

I am new to IIS, honestly I've only been on it a few times, but I have a new requirement to track the number of times people access links within certain folders (our website is basically a set of pages that use IIS Directory Browsing to make files available), and then build a report for each of the "watched" directories that shows number of accesses and date last accessed.

What I'm thinking of is writing some code that parses an IIS7 log or report that looks for the specific folders, and then uses a counter to find number of times accessed and the last time accessed.  My question is, does IIS7 provide a built-in utility to build the data of when links are accessed?  It's fine if you can't tell it to watch certain links but instead record all traffic, the parser can look for certain strings to find the folder accesses needed.

I can't use any 3rd party solutions, just what is native to IIS7.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a tool that already does that there are plenty out there such as AWStats http://awstats.sourceforge.net/ or you could also just use LogParser to parse the logs easily and produce reports based on that http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2010/03/25/analyze-your-iis-log-files-favorite-log-parser-queries.aspx